# Does the order of decorators matter on a Flask view?

Tags: python, flask, python-decorators, flask-login

I'm using the `login_required` decorator and another decorator which paginates output data.  Is it important which one comes first?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

While there probably won't be any problem in this case no matter what the order, you probably want `login_required` to execute first so that you don't make queries and paginate results that will just get thrown away.

Decorators wrap the original function bottom to top, so when the function is called the wrapper added by each decorator executes top to bottom. `@login_required` should be below any other decorators that assume the user is logged in so that its condition is evaluated before those others.

`@app.route()` must always be the top, outermost decorator. Otherwise the route will be registered for a function that does not represent all the decorators.

---

The broader answer is that it depends on what each of the decorators are doing. You need to think about the flow of your program and whether it would make logical sense for one to come before the other.

Answer (score 4):

according the implement of login_required,

```
def login_required(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def decorated_view(*args, **kwargs):
        if current_app.login_manager._login_disabled:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        elif not current_user.is_authenticated():
            return current_app.login_manager.unauthorized()
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated_view
```

You should do it like below.

```
@login_required
@paginate
def view_function():
    pass
```

suppose you have another decorator is_admin to judge a user have admin permission, you should do it like below

```
@login_required
@is_admin
def view_function():
    pass
```

Answer (score 4):

The Flask documentation specifies that the order matters if the function is a view and has a `route` decorator. From [the docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/viewdecorators/):

> When applying further decorators, always remember that the
>   route() decorator is the outermost.

Answer (score 2):

According to [PEP 318](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/) the syntax for function decorators is:

```
@dec2
@dec1
def func(arg1, arg2, ...):
    pass
```

this is equivalent to:

```
def func(arg1, arg2, ...):
    pass
func = dec2(dec1(func))
```

and dec1 is called before dec2.

You can define these functions to check like this:

```
def dec1(func):
    print 'dec1'
def dec2(func):
    print 'dec2'

@dec2
@dec1
def func():
    pass
dec1
dec2
```

Actually it does not make any error but if you use `login_reqired` first and user is not logged in application will process data and paginate it after that `login_required` function generates an abort

Best implementation for login_required decorator in flask is:

```
@paginate
@login_required
def view_function():
    pass
```

Comment: Although everything leading up to the conclusion in your answer is *technically correct*, your conclusion is **absolutely wrong**.


You want to put the `@login_required` above the `@paginate`--let me explain why...

Even though the decorators do *technically* execute from bottom to top, what you have to remember is that when the decorator executes, it returns a *wrapper*. The wrapper is where the core functionality of the decorator should execute... and **decorator wrappers execute top to bottom**.